# Как сделать смс-оповещение?

Tags: php

Всем привет! Написал мини-аукцион для своего сайт. Возник такой вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы мне на телефон приходило смс-уведомление, когда кто-нибудь купит что-нибудь на моём аукционе? :) Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые операторы заводят ящики для абонентов, например, `11111111111@operator.ru` и при отправке писем на этот адрес, они приходят на телефон как смс)

**Не реклама, просто подробности:**

> E-mail — электронная почта через SMS
> Услуга позволяет отправлять и получать
> электронную почту с помощью мобильного
> телефона в виде SMS-сообщений. Вы
> можете самостоятельно управлять
> услугой с помощью SMS-сообщений
> отправляемых на сервисный номер 508.
> Внимание! Все команды необходимо
> набирать заглавными латинскими
> буквами. Прежде чем начать работу с
> электронной почтой на мобильном
> телефоне, необходимо создать учетную
> запись отправив команду: C В
> результате Вы сможете получать и
> отправлять электронную почту c адреса:
> +7924XXXXXXX@sms.megafondv.ru где XXXXXXX – номер вашего мобильного
> телефона. Для того чтобы удалить
> учетную запись и отказаться от
> получения и отправки электронной почты
> необходимо отправить команду: D Вы
> можете временно заблокировать учетную
> запись, для этого отправьте команду: B
> Для того чтобы разблокировать учетную
> запись отправьте команду: U После того
> как ваша учетная запись создана вы
> можете добавить до трех псевдонимов,
> которые позволят Вам принимать
> эелектронную почту на адреса вида:
> (псевдоним)@sms.megafondv.ru Псевдоним
> не должен начинаться с цифры, размер
> букв не учитывается. Например:
> ivanov@sms.megafondv.ru Для того чтобы
> добавить псевдоним отправьте команду:
> A(псевдоним) Например: Aivanov
> Внимание! Добавление псевдонима
> отменяет отправку или получение
> электронной почты с адреса
> +7924XXXXXXX@sms.megafondv.ru. Для возобновления отправки и получения
> электронной почты на этот адрес
> необходимо удалить или заблокировать
> все добавленные псевдонимы. Для того
> чтобы удалить псевдоним отправьте
> команду: R(псевдоним) Для просмотра
> всех ваших адресов электронной почты
> отправьте команду: L Получение
> электронной почты После настройки
> учетной записи вся почта приходящая на
> адрес вида: (номер телефона или
> псевдоним)@sms.megafondv.ru
> автоматически преобразуется в одно или
> несколько SMS-сообщений на ваш
> мобильный телефон. Если отправленное
> Вам электронное письмо больше размера
> одного SMS-сообщения (160 символов для
> латиницы и 70 для кириллицы) то
> оставшая часть сообщения обрезается.
> Вы можете самостоятельно установить
> режим в котором длиные письма будут
> разбиваться на несколько SMS-сообщений
> (до 6). Для этого отправьте команду:
> N(количество сообщений) Если ваш
> мобильный телефон поддерживает функцию
> приема объединенных SMS сообщений то
> Вы можете принимать длиные письма в
> виде одного сообщения. Для включения
> режима оттправки объединенных
> SMS-сообщений отправьте команду: T1
> Для отмены отправки объединенных
> SMS-сообщений отправьте команду: T0
> Изменить формат получаемых email
> сообщений вы можете с помощью команд:
> F0 – отправитель, тема, тело. F1 –
> отправитель, тема. F2 – отправитель,
> тело. Отправка электронной почты Для
> того чтобы отправить сообщение на
> адрес электронной почты достаточно
> послать на сервисный номер 509
> SMS-сообщение вида: (адрес электронной
> почты)(пробел)(текст сообщения)
> Например: ivanov@mail.ru Привет! Как у
> тебя дела? Можно отправить сообщение
> сразу нескольким адресатам перечислив
> их адреса через запятую, например:
> ivanov@mail.ru,petrov@mail.ru Привет
> друзья! Как у вас дела? В качестве
> адреса отправителя будет указан адрес
> вида:
> +7924XXXXXXX@sms.megafondv.ru где XXXXXXX – номер вашего телефона. Или
> если у вас создан один или несколько
> псевдонимов то от имени первого
> созданного псевдонима в виде:
> (псевдоним)@sms.megafondv.ru Стоимость
> услуги Услуга предоставляется без
> абонентской платы и платы за
> подключение. Стоимость SMS-сообщений
> зависит от выбранного вами тарифного
> плана.

Comment: А можно чуть-чуть поподробнее? Спасибо!

Comment: ответил выше

Comment: Сколько стоит отправка смс на номер 508&

Comment: спс =) ибовам

Comment: >Сколько стоит отправка смс на номер 508&

vinnie

>Стоимость SMS-сообщений зависит от выбранного вами тарифного плана.

Comment: А как его выбрать? тарифный план

Comment: Блин ты что вчера родился? Мобильный телефон у тебя есть? Сколько смс и звонки стоят знаешь? Если не знаешь сходи к своему оператору он расскажет. Спроси про услугу называется: E-mail — электронная почта через SMS

все раскажут

Comment: vinnie
>Стоимость услуги
>Услуга предоставляется без абонентской платы и платы за подключение.